# Logging downloaded files in excel using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I can successfully download files from server using the macro below, but sometimes the file name may be incorrect so that I have to manually go through the directory and compare what was downloaded versus what should have been downloaded which has become very time consuming. What do I need to include in this macro to make it provide of log of what was not downloaded?

```
Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, _
ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long
Sub imagedownloader()
    Dim i As Long, url As String
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") 'must use the name of the sheet to do this
    For i = 1 To 4 'Where 4 is the number of items in the list (can be made dynamic)
        DoEvents
        url = "http://mydomain.com/images/" & .Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg"
        URLDownloadToFile 0, url, "C:\downloads\images\" & .Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg", 0, 0
    Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are trying? (**UNTESTED**)

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, _
ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Sub imagedownloader()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim filesize As Integer
    Dim FlName As String, url As String
    
    FlName = "C:\downloads\images\Log.Txt"
    
    '~~> get a free file handle
    filesize = FreeFile()
  
    '~~> Open your file
    Open FlName For Output As #filesize
    
    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 1 To 4
            url = "http://mydomain.com/images/" & .Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg"
            
            URLDownloadToFile 0, url, "C:\downloads\images\" & .Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg", 0, 0
            
            DoEvents
            
            If DoesFileExist("C:\downloads\images\" & .Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg") Then
                Print #filesize, .Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg - Successfully Downloaded"
            Else
                Print #filesize, .Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg - Not Downloaded"
            End If
        Next
    End With
    
    Close #filesize
End Sub

Public Function DoesFileExist(FilePath As String) As Boolean
    On Error GoTo Whoa
    If Not Dir(FilePath, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then DoesFileExist = True
Whoa:
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

**FOLLOWUP**

Here is an advanced version (**TESTED AND TRIED**). This is required because `URLDownloadToFile` will download a file even if it is not available. The only thing in this case would be that the image file would be corrupt.

The best way to handle this is create a userform and add an image control. You can set the image control's visible property to false if you want. Now use this code. I have commented it so you will have not problems in understanding it :)

```
Option Explicit

Private Declare Function URLDownloadToFile Lib "urlmon" _
Alias "URLDownloadToFileA" (ByVal pCaller As Long, ByVal szURL As String, _
ByVal szFileName As String, ByVal dwReserved As Long, ByVal lpfnCB As Long) As Long

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim filesize As Integer
    Dim FlName As String, url As String

    FlName = "C:\downloads\images\Log.Txt"

    '~~> Get a free file handle
    filesize = FreeFile()

    '~~> Open your file
    Open FlName For Output As #filesize

    With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
        For i = 1 To 4
            url = "http://capnhud.host22.com/examples/" & .Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg"

            URLDownloadToFile 0, url, "C:\downloads\images\" & .Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg", 0, 0

            DoEvents
            
            '~~> Try to load the downloaded image to Image1 Control
            On Error Resume Next
            Set Image1.Picture = LoadPicture("C:\downloads\images\" & .Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg")
            '~~> If image is not in the correct format then delete it
            If Not Err.Number = 0 Then
                Kill "C:\downloads\images\" & .Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg"
                Print #filesize, .Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg - Not Downloaded"
            Else
                Print #filesize, .Range("A" & i).Value & ".jpg - Successfully Downloaded"
            End If
        Next
    End With

    Close #filesize
End Sub
```

**SNAPSHOT**

[image]

**NOTE**: You now actually don't need `DoesFileExist` function. You can do the writing to the text in `If Not Err.Number = 0 Then` as well.

**SAMPLE FILE**

http://wikisend.com/download/310908/Sample.xlsm

HTH

Comment: running the above results in Compile Error: Sub or Function not defined on the line that has 'If DoesFileExist'

Comment: What is the value of `.Range("A" & i).Value` at the time of error?

Comment: by value are you referring to the filename?

Comment: Yes. Also did you copy the function `Public Function DoesFileExist(FilePath As String) As Boolean`

Comment: Ok I was missing that part and when I added it to the macro the error becomes `Run-time error 76 path not found`. I click debug and it takes me to the line that says `Open FlName For Output As #filesize` the value is the name of a file that I know for sure exists.

Comment: Do you have a folder called `images` in `C:\downloads`?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11578/discussion-between-capnhud-and-siddharth-rout)

Comment: The above solution does exactly what I was wanting. Thank you Siddharth for your assistance.